# 413 Request Entity Too Large (nginx openstack glance)

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

Deployed openstack using Helm chart. Problem with downloading the image via the web; when trying to download the image, `413 Request Entity Too Large`. The configurations are set to default `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"`.

Part of the ingress deployment code, where Nginx settings are applied:

###### ingress_component.yaml

```yaml
ingress:
    node_port:
      enabled: false
      http_port: 30080
      https_port: 30443
    annotations:
      # NOTE(portdirect): if left blank this is populated from
      # .deployment.cluster.class
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: null
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
        more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: deny";
        more_set_headers "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none";
        more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'";
external_policy_local: false
```

###### ingress-kube-system.yaml

```yaml
 ingress:
    node_port:
      enabled: false
      http_port: 30080
      https_port: 30443
    annotations:
      # NOTE(portdirect): if left blank this is populated from
      # .deployment.cluster.class
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: null
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
        more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: deny";
        more_set_headers "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none";
        more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'";
```

I tried adding the parameter `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "0"` the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The external ingress received the value 1M

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).